# Spacetime translation of Noether's current density

Tags: mathematical-modeling, symmetry

I've heard so many times that spacetime translation invariance is assumed when we speak about Noether's current density. Could someone explain to me, why is that so? What if we don't assume it?

To be precise, where did we get an idea for assuming something like that?

I am, of course, familiar with conservation law and continuity equation that Noether's charges and current satisfy, but I still don't see why is spacetime translation always being assumed...

I'm looking forward to hearing from somebody here.

Comment: Are you familiar with Noether's theorem? Different symmetries give different conserved charges.

Comment: +1. Welcome to our new community! Thank you so much for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! Do you have any answer to Anyon's question?  We generally close abandoned questions after a couple weeks if it looks like the OP is no longer interested (i.e. not answering follow-up questions). This has led to our (small) unanswered queue being very manageable. @Anyon is your comment expandable a bit? Most people with physics undergrad degrees will be familiar with Noether's theorem right? Is there something more specific you wanted to say or ask?

Comment: @NikeDattani Most who have taken classical mechanics should indeed be familiar with the theorem. But those who have probably wouldn't say that spacetime translation invariance is always assumed, since other common examples like rotational symmetry would be mentioned in proper courses. So my comment was intended to probe OP's background, in order to gauge what an appropriate answer might look like.

Comment: @Anyon hopefully Bojan tells us a bit more about their background (especially in terms of their understanding of Noether's theorem)! Bojan: You have an ***unregistered*** account which is starting to accumulate a good amount of reputation both here and on Physics.SE, but if you don't register the account you could lose access to it permanently (wouldn't be able to sign into the same account again): It can be quite convenient to have a registered account because then we can look at our entire history of questions, answers, votes, etc., but if for some reason you don't want to do it, it's ok.

Comment: @Anyon You're not answering my question. You've also misunderstood me. Who says I didn't know Noether's theorem? You are totally wrong. I'm just interested to know the explanation of introducing such approximation. Why is it always assumed if nothing else specific was taken into account in the first place?

Comment: @BojanObradovic Sorry, but then I still don't really understand what answer you're looking for. Energy and momentum conservation are linked to time and spatial translation symmetry, respectively. Combined spacetime translation invariance leads to conservation of the stress-energy tensor. Those symmetries hold in many systems of interest (at least approximately), but if they don't, in general those quantities won't be conserved. Which would make math. modeling more complicated. It's definitively more convenient to make those assumptions if possible. C.f. assumptions of no air drag in mechanics.

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.